# Avoiding duplicating data when using SuperClass

Tags: oop, matlab, pass-by-reference

I am developing a MATLAB OOP project for the first time. My parent class will have a very large matrix which the children(many) need to access. How can I prevent the children from duplicating the data ?

In pseudo code I require that,

```
classdef parent
    properties
        largeMatrix;
    end
end
classdef child < parent
    methods
        function obj = child(parent)
             Data.parent of this child = Share from parent
        end
        ...
        something = largeMatrix(n,m);
    end
end
p = parent; p.largeMatrix = rand(100);
c1 = child(p);
c2 = child(p);
```

Both children c1 and c2 should access same data created in the original `rand(100)`, but should not be copying the `largeMatrix` as I need many children, and would like the program to be memory efficient. The `largeMatrix` will be read from a file.

PS: This is the first time I am posting in this forum, so do forgive me if I have posted it wrongly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A class is just a data type, it does not hold any data. If you instantiate an object `parent` of the `Parent` class, and then an object `child` of the `Child` class, then by default `child` will not inherit any data from `parent`.  You can copy the data from one object to another by using a copy constructor.

```
child = parent;  % this copies the data in `parent` to `child`
```

However, in this case Matlab creates a copy of the data in `parent`.

You can avoid copying the data by using [handle objects](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/comparing-handle-and-value-classes.html). You can assign the handle object to multiple variables or pass it to functions without causing MATLAB to make a copy of the original object. For example,

```
classdef A < handle
    properties
        largeMatrix;  % wrap your large data into a handle class
    end
end

classdef B
    properties
        data;
    end
    methods
        function obj = B(mydata)
            obj.data = mydata;
        end
    end
end
```

Then in the main program you can assign

```
a = A();
a.largeMatrix = rand(100);
b1 = B(a);   
b2 = B(a);
b3 = b1;    % can even do this

% no copies of largeMatrix were made, because `a` is a handle object

% accessing largeMatrix
b1.data.largeMatrix 
b3.data.largeMatrix
```

Comment: It is not true that by simply creating the child even if parent not handle that MATLAB copies the data.
The copy happens only if you modify the data within the child.

Answer (score 2):

MATLAB **copies the array on write**.

Suppose that your `parent` class is (no need to subclass a handle):

```
classdef parent
    properties
        largeMatrix;
    end
end
```

and your `child` class is:

```
classdef child < parent
    methods
        function obj = child(parent)
            obj.largeMatrix = parent.largeMatrix;
        end
    end
end
```

Now, let's create parent and assign a large matrix to its property `largeMatrix`:

```
p = parent;
p.largeMatrix = rand(1e4); % 750 MB circa
```

Check out the jump in the memory:

[image]

Now, let's create a child and check that the data was referenced:

```
c = child(p);
size(c.largeMatrix)
```

As you can see no jump in the memory:

[image]

Finally, let's make a simple change in the child's data:

```
c.largeMatrix(1) = 1;
```

As you can see, only **on write the array is effectively copied**:

[image]

To prevent writes on `child.largeMatrix` define the property in the parent class with attribute `(Abstract = true)` and in the child `(SetAccess = immutable)`.